# Cleaning up NSDocument subclasses

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsdocument

I need to perform some cleanup operations in my `NSDocument` subclass when documents are closed.

With the current implementation having that cleanup code in `canCloseDocumentWithDelegate:shouldCloseSelector:contextInfo:` it only gets called when the document has any unsaved changed.

Even the `close` method doesn't look like a good place - according to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/close) *This method may not always be called.*

Is there one place to put that kind of code that's **always** called before a `NSDocument` instance is destructed..?

There's some [really neat message flow diagrams](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/AdvancedTopics/AdvancedTopics.html) for initializing, opening and saving `NSDocuments` in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/ManagingLifecycle/ManagingLifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH4-SW1) - alas none for closing documents or quitting the app?!

Answer (score 0):

Your NSDocument lives in a window.

Why not set some object (e.g. your subclassed NSDocument object) as a delegate for the NSWindow that hosts the document and then catch the ["`windowWillClose:`" notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillClose%3a)?

Comment: I could think of a dozen workarounds - I was however wondering what's the official, supported way in the `NSDocument` class... in an application framework that's been around for decades which surely has built-in support for such a basic use case :-)